# how to process arbitrary messages as data in Max/MSP?

Tags: max-msp

In other words, how can I prevent data-processing objects from interpreting certain messages they receive as instructions?

Example:

```
msg{a b c} -> obj{prepend set} -> msg{set a b c}
```

Actual (prepend intercepts the 'set' message)

```
msg{set q} -> obj{prepend set} (no output)
msg{a b c} -> obj{prepend set} -> msg{q a b c}
```

Desired (prepend treats all messages as data)

```
msg{set a b c} -> obj{prepend set} -> msg{set set a b c}
```

Answer (score 1):

[sprintf set set %s %s %s] might also get you what you want.

Hens Zimmerman

```
----------begin_max5_patcher----------
521.3ocyUE1ajBBD8y5uBBI22rMBJ558W4RSCtxsklUz.Xusoo+2OYPy51yz
psm2dIJ5LN.u2iYFeIL.W1bRXvnui9AJH3kvf.vkyQvfc.tleZ+QtABCqD+p
o7Qbj+SVwIK31hJG8Iq.O8QcCgM5T0UKUGEVXQHmc1zYeqWi84iBXIFmbK2t
+Ao5v8ZwdqGrjco2FGgHTp6AMebDc2vb7Kr84VgeB3Rt5.Fcm6quFF5FhVJk
6pKE54nG4coWKWyqEVg9dghW54T7rTmtFpSKX2x5Yaliyr3Ol43nMg8EWExS
S+uf74WCxSXISHOEdeCIesvX3GD+QstQXQt6zcnrXDIeF4Y95d5Wut2ycZVB
T8mls.M3ycvOeaNSqVpr+DMJAey3ulQBRlUBR9Kz5aHKHdGnAYjETDbgF.wg
OJUusyOrYN+WJLllN89wkZruG571UILVohakMpoAwtHnGjUUB0zBgZYUaSuZ
N.hjXFvm3B3QAPRv57FIMtpIPiim8PcwLfs.FjrNBLB4Bet4PJpyZCHPwFbB
PSR+GdBPV3I.c0oPLXbhwUR+cnmrZ42i9IFa.5y2free9tG8SL1.zmr.zyVm
1O.XZxtIvGr9P766lxaaeRnMCf.fd+OTdrQ6Lyi.SoxaBc6wZwSxw3ATg459
V81997cZ+OANkkh8SsoRnUcRX1gtc90vemCElhN
-----------end_max5_patcher-----------
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can. There is usually a way round though, for example you could use [combine] or [zl.join] to achieve the result you're after.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the tosymbol and fromsymbol objects:

```
----------begin_max5_patcher----------
494.3oc2UssabCBD8Y6uBDO6VY7k014WIopxWllPjMXA3zcUT92qYvNwa61M
Nq1ZE0W.MCy.mygggm88nUx8flRtgbKwy6YeOOzk0g2jsGsqbecaoFCi1AZc
48.MvslA1aP+ZvPtCGKIUj56nyQzxEPsbPfgEM4TNXZAi4PO3NaJk7sok5Uf
FDlRCWJ9tBpMtHhC280v.BqfYmBmFdKqRS8Cbw8mNiz.RJlRb5hb3MHxkUO9
EVzLbECcbwH1zKgq1bnEQJcQXNNfwwrNew22NDrRgT.+b7j+Cc7GJYm9PWkr
ktBs5DrNK1Rzn3D6zjQzeg0rSxZ11yZi7JvYVQtcJs3rbN7+KNGwdeNWr4T9
bcIdsGw0tCQR9hJ+U0gHIByHCmNeGhceVZPLx9dPzXkQ5kqUYXACKMe0Z0T8
lKirjyUuk8opd6nZsKQpPhmm7AUJWBo6NmPke0JpvcGeI8a+li.z5+X0SKGT
0yZvzcF4ML1.ZCWfRwhXr+RRXuFzC7lF.WObNMttrpEPBFdxqw0BG6WSuKd1
scvIbMxywX9eIdV0sU3lAmhU.mrMCM4q.MEWHZbuyJ66eBT5osDAxX+nGkJq
YV.ZxENSbGoJ3I9b7wnmR0XiCyXWiAk6Q99b2eLzNYCnDC7o23im7K9+BLS8
oxM
-----------end_max5_patcher-----------
```